# Error datos: TypeError row.save is not a function

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Estoy realizando una aplicación con NodeJs, TypeScript y MongoDB. Estoy realizando la gestión e inserción de errores en la base de datos. El código que he realizado es el siguiente:

```
import { IActionResult } from "../models/ActionResult";
import { IError, IErrorDocument, IErrorFilter } from "../models/Error";
const dbUtils = require("../lib/utils/db");

export class ErrorsManager{
/**
 *
 * @param newError
 * @returns Promise<IActionResult<IError>>
 */

public async addError(newError: IError): Promise<IActionResult<IErrorDocument>> {
    try {
      let row = dbUtils.insertRow(Error, newError);
      return row;
    } catch (err) {
      return Promise.reject(err);
    }
  };
  
 

/**
 * get error by name
 * @param name
 * @returns
 */
public async GetByNameAsync(name: string, fields?:string): Promise<IErrorDocument> {
  try {
    let query = dbUtils.getRecord(Error, name, fields);
    return query;
  } catch (err) {
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
};

}
```

El modelo:

```
'use strict';



import { Model, model,Schema, ObjectId, Document } from 'mongoose';



/*  Model Interfaces    */

// name, message, stack, count. reportDate
export interface IError {
    name : string;
    message : string;
    stack: string,
    count: number;
    reportDate?: Date;
};

export interface IErrorFilter{
  reportDate?:Date;
  name?:String;
}

export interface IErrorDocument extends Document, IError{}




/*  DB Model    */
const errorSchema = new Schema<IErrorDocument>({
  name : String,
  message : String,
  stack: String,
  count: Number,
  reportDate: Date,

  });



const Error: Model<IErrorDocument> = model<IErrorDocument>("Error", errorSchema);

export {Error}
```

Y para hacer el guardado de los errores:

```
"use strict";

import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { ErrorsManager } from "../managers/ErrorsManager";
import { IActionResult } from "../models/ActionResult";
import { IError, IErrorDocument } from "../models/Error";
const dbUtils = require("../lib/utils/db");
let mongoose = require('mongoose');

.......


export function responseException(res: Response, error: Error) {

  let errorManager: ErrorsManager = new ErrorsManager();

  let errorInterface: IError = {
    name: null,
    count: 0,
    reportDate: null,
    stack: null,
    message: null,
  };

  errorInterface.name = error.name;
  errorInterface.message = error.message;
  errorInterface.stack = error.stack;
  errorInterface.count = 1;
  errorInterface.reportDate = new Date(Date.now());

  console.log( "Error datos: " + errorInterface.name+ " "+ error.message);
  if(errorManager.GetByNameAsync(error.name) !== undefined || errorManager.GetByNameAsync(error.name) !== null){
    errorInterface.count++;
  }else{
    errorManager.addError(errorInterface);
  }

  res.statusCode = 400;
  res.send(error.stack);
}

......
```

Pero el problema es que, al intentar guardar en Bd, me aparece:

> Error datos: TypeError row.save is not a function

Viene de la función:

```
db.insertRow = function (Model, obj): Promise<any> {
    try {

        let row = new Model();
        for (let prop in obj) {
            row[prop] = obj[prop];
        }

        let now = new Date();
        row.updatedAt = now;
        row.createdAt = now;

        return row.save();
    } catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
};
```

Me funciona con todos los modelos anteriores, pero con este no. ¿Por qué me aparece el mensaje de que no es una función? La estructura que he utilizado para error es idéntica a la estructura que he utilizado para otros modelos.

Comment: Este error es porque la variable que usa el método no es una instancia que pueda usar insertRow o que la variable o clase no sea una valida para la función, es decir que tal vez dicho metodo se tiene que usar con un objecto de la clase DB pero la variable donde se usa no es una instancia de la clase DB, haz un console log para verificar

Comment: De acuerdo. Gracias

Comment: Mi pregunta es ¿Porqué escogiste `Error` como nombre de tu Modelo? Recuerda que JavaScript tiene su propio objeto llamado `Error`, ¿qué probabilidad hay de que se esté creando una instancia del Objeto `Error` de Javascript que de tu propio Modelo? Te sugiero que cambies el nombre del Modelo a algo distinto de `Error` y hagas la prueba. Comenta el resultado. Saludos

Comment: Pues, efectivamente, cambiando el nombre a ErrorCustom, se solucionó el problema. Gracias por vuestros aportes.